# HINTERNET InternetOpenUrl() on linux C

Tags: c, windows, linux, function

I am a native windows programmer and I was just starting to develop some applications on linux. I was wondering if there is a linux function similar to InternetOpenUrl(). I wanted to use this so I could open the [Speakeasy speed test](http://speakeasy.net/speed) to download random images according to size to "speed test" internet connections. If there isn't a similar command does anyone have some C code for initiating a http socket to a server to download a file (or code to do the same on a ftp although i rather not use ftp). I would rather use the InternetOpenUrl() alternative if there is one but i am also open to other methods as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), which incidentally also works on Windows.

Comment: this would work actually, but i have a small question. if i were to statically link the binary would it include all the code from this library or just of the functions i use. there are some instances where i need to statically link my library and/or compile to an ARM architecture. (im not really afraid of file size but if it could be kept minimal it would be better.

Comment: That would depend on your linker.